# Программное обращение к maxLength

Tags: android, android-edittext

Подскажите, как программно узнать значение `maxLength` объекта `EditText`?

Answer (score 1):

C API>21 можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33889970/3212712):

```
for (InputFilter filter : mEditText.getFilters()) {
    if (filter instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
        ((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filter).getMax();
    }
}
```

До него - через [рефлексию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755012/3212712) (по ссылке указано почему так делать не стоит):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static int getMaxLengthForTextView(TextView textView)
{
    int maxLength = -1;

    for (InputFilter filter : textView.getFilters()) {
        if (filter instanceof InputFilter.LengthFilter) {
            try {
                Field maxLengthField = filter.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMax");
                maxLengthField.setAccessible(true);

                if (maxLengthField.isAccessible()) {
                    maxLength = maxLengthField.getInt(filter);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                Log.w(filter.getClass().getName(), e);
            } // if an Exception is thrown, Log it and return -1
        }
    }

return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: InputFilter.LengthFilter здесь значение?

Comment: Вот значение: `((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filter).getMax());`

Comment: Что то не получается применить.

Comment: ((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filter).getMax()); как связать с EditText?

Comment: Ну... Внутри цикла это выражение вернёт максимальное кол-во символов для поля ввода с именем `mEditText`

Comment: Так значение не int.

Comment: @Alexandr, а какое? Если long - ну просто скастуйте к int...

Comment: Не могу приложить пример, т.к пишу с телефона суть есть объект есть макс длина, программа добавляет 0 сколько необходимо до Макс. С каким значением необходимо сравнивать длину?

Comment: @Alexandr, со значением из моего второго комментария

Comment: Извините, но последний вопрос. Напишите пожалуйста пример как сохранить в переменную.

Comment: @Alexandr, `int max = ((InputFilter.LengthFilter) filter).getMax();`...